# Two-legged OAuth Provider Ruby

Tags: ruby, oauth, oauth-ruby

Does anyone know of any examples of a two-legged Oauth provider in ruby? Preferably one done using the oauth gem.

Thanks.

Edit: I was able to solve this, it was surprisingly simple, which explains the lack of examples.

Comment: want to point to a how-to anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

check out this thread. It should work if you are using oauth-plugin.

[Rails two-legged OAuth provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775242/rails-two-legged-oauth-provider)